# Getting Error " Can't contact LDAP server" using PHP ldap_bind function

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have to bind Active Directory user with server. I can successfully connect with server but somehow can not bind user.I do not know whats the reason.

Following is my PHP source code:

```
$basedn="dc=domain,dc=com";
echo "Connecting ...<br/>";
$ds=ldap_connect("192.XXX.XXX.XX");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "connect result is ".$ds."<br/>";

if($ds){
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $lb=ldap_bind($ds,"cn=xyz,o=domain.com","password");
    if ($lb) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP-Errno: " . ldap_errno($ds) . "<br />";
        echo "LDAP-Error: " . ldap_error($ds) . "<br />";
    }       

    ldap_close($ds);
}
```

Can you please give me what exactly I have to pass username parameter in `ldap_bind` function? Please provide me any source code that help me to do so?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the result code from the bind response?

Answer (score 1):

I am on a domain controller running Server 2008 R2 on a domain that was originally 2003 and had to use the login@domain format.  I verified the DN was correct and pre-2008 domain admin accounts could connect using the DN.  However, non-admins could not unless the login@domain format was used.

Now, my code tries:

$lb = ldap_bind($ds, "cn=login,o=domain.com", "password");

and then if nothing found, tries:

$lb = ldap_bind($ds, "login@domain.com", "password");

This is a quick fix while I troubleshoot the cause of the DN not working.  I would recommend that even though you are using 2008, try the 2003 format.

Answer (score 0):

Using Active Directory on Windows Server 2003, instead of:

```
$lb = ldap_bind($ds, "cn=login,o=domain.com", "password");
```

I had to use:

```
$lb = ldap_bind($ds, "login@domain.com", "password");
```

However, your error message (*can't contact LDAP server*) looks like you did not provide to `ldap_connect()` a server address *reachable* by your PHP script (check Windows firewall, etc.)